# New to Perl and was wondering why my code isn't doing what it's supposed to

Tags: string, perl, input

I have an assignment asking me to print x iterations of a string for each character in that string. So if the string input is `"Gum"`, then it should print out:

```
Gum  
Gum  
Gum
```

Right now my code is

```
my $string = <>;
my $length = length($string);
print ($string x $length, "\n");
```

And I'm getting gum printed five times as my output.

Comment: Try it with 
my $string="Gum"; 
please.

Comment: @ChankeyPathak I am running from Padre right now and I tried taking out the spaces and I'm still getting the same result. Maybe a picture will help.

http://i.imgur.com/PvWh8Bt.png

Comment: @boucekv Yeah it works fine if $string="gum"; but I was told to use standard input.

Comment: @user3591912: Check out jackrabbit's answer.

Answer (score 7):

As you are simply using the input string, it still contains the newline at the end. This is also counted as a character. On my system, it outputs 4 `Gum\n`.

`chomp($string)` will remove the line ending, but the output will then also run together, resulting in `GumGumGum\n`

Comment: The string ends in just a newline on any platform, *not* in CR + LF

Comment: I have never used Perl on Windows. Thanks for clarifying that. I'll change my answer.

Answer (score 7):

Those who have said you will get CR + LF at the end of the line on a Windows system are mistaken. Perl will convert the native line ending to a simple newline `\n` on any platform.

You must bear this in mind whether you are reading from the terminal or from a file.

The built-in [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) function will remove the line terminator character from the end of a string variable. If the string doesn't end with a line terminator then it will have no effect.

So when you type <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>u</kbd><kbd>m</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> you are setting `$string` to `"Gum\n"`, and `length` will show that it has four characters.

You are seeing it *five* times on your screen because the first line is what you typed in yourself. The following four are printed by the program.

After a `chomp`, `$string` is just `"Gum"` with a length of three characters, which is what you want.

To output this on separate lines you have to print a newline after each line, so you can write

```
my $string = <>;
chomp $string;
my $length = length $string;
print ("$string\n" x $length);
```

or perhaps

```
print $string, "\n" for 1 .. $length;
```

I hope that helps

Comment: I know a guy who, to this day, carries a Perl v4 .exe around with him.  Given an ancient enough implementation of Perl, the OP may in fact be seeing CR LF line endings. Replacing `chop()` with `chomp()` was the 1st iteration to solving this problem prior to the `:crlf` IO Layer.

Comment: @tjd: If the OP was getting `"Gum\r\n"` from the `readline` then it would be printing the string *five* times, so there would be *six* lines of text including the characters echoed from the keyboard. Since the string appears only five times the input string must be `"Gum\n"`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine. See this: http://ideone.com/AsPFh3

**Possibility 1:** It might be that you're putting 2 spaces while giving input from command line, that's why the length comes out to be 5, and it prints 5 times. Something like this: http://ideone.com/fsvnrd

In above case the `my $string=<>;` will give you `my $string = "gum  ";` so length will be 5.

**Possibility 2:**
Another possibility is that if you use Windows then it will add carriage return (`\r`) and new line (due to enter `\n`) at the end of string. So it makes the length 5.

**Edit**: To print in new line: Use the below code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# your code goes here
chomp(my $string=<>);
my $length = length($string);
print ("$string\n" x $length);
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/PXcldr)

**Edit 2**: To remove `\r\n` use the below:

`$string=~ s/\r|\n//g;` Read more [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=504638).

Comment: Works in ideone, but it still returns four iterations when I run it on padre with chomp($string). I think it's doing what you you mentioned earlier, how windows is adding the carriage return and new line.

Comment: The string ends in just a newline on any platform, *not* in CR + LF

Comment: Thanks Borodin. Didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

When You insert input and press enter afterwards You don't enter "Gum" but  "Gum\r\n" which is a string of length 5. You should do trimming.

Comment: Yep, followed jackrabbits advice and chomped off $string, but now I'm left with "GumGumGum" instead of new lines after each "Gum".

Comment: Check my answer, I've shown code to print new line.

Comment: If You want to display with new line chomp it only when taking length instead of reassigning. 

"my $length = length(chomp($string)) ". Or concatenate it while displaying

Comment: The string ends in just a newline on any platform, *not* in CR + LF